# Имею канвас, нажимаю на любую точку UI и он прокликиваеться на сцену

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

При нажатии на любую точку на UI допустим панель и за канвасом на заднем плане на сцене стоит любой объект. При клике он прокликаться через канвас и если там будет объект он нажмет на него
***настройки канваса:***[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на выделенный объект который находиться за канвасом он будет выбран и событие OnMouseDown выполнит действие, его видно на след картинке с прозрачным фоном. **Мне нужно что бы активным был только UI элемент**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты случайно не убирал с панели галочку `Raycast Target` ?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте Raycast Target у элементов, которые не должны прокликивать